# How to create a new dataframe from the products of columns of an existing dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with *n* columns. I would like to create a new dataframe that contains all the existing columns as well as all possible products of any 2 (ab,ac,...), 3(abc, abd, ...) , 4(abcd, abce,...), 5(abcde, abcdf, ...), ..., and n(abcdef...) columns. The only criteria is the absence of repeating columns in any product. Here is an example for *n=3*:

**original df:**

```
col1: a
col2: b
col3: c
```

**modified df:**

```
col1: a
col2: b
col3: c
col4: a*b
col5: a*c
col6: b*c
col7: a*b*c
```

What is the most efficient way to create such dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would construct a [`powerset`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.powerset), then [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) it :

```
# pip install more_itertools
from more_itertools import powerset

N = df.shape[1] # Nb of columns

out = (
    df.assign(
        **{
        col: df.eval(col)
        for col in map("*".join, list(powerset(df.columns))[N+1:])
        }
    )
)
```

*NB : If you can't install more_itertools, you can use [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe from the docs :*

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Output :

```
# powerset
[(),
 ('a',),
 ('b',),
 ('c',),
 ('a', 'b'),      # we moved the cursor up to this one with N+1 == 4
 ('a', 'c'),      # to avoid evaluating empty string and original cols
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c')]

# out
     a    b    c  a*b  a*c  b*c  a*b*c
0 0.55 0.72 0.60 0.39 0.33 0.43   0.24
1 0.54 0.42 0.65 0.23 0.35 0.27   0.15
2 0.44 0.89 0.96 0.39 0.42 0.86   0.38
3 0.38 0.79 0.53 0.30 0.20 0.42   0.16
4 0.57 0.93 0.07 0.53 0.04 0.07   0.04
5 0.09 0.02 0.83 0.00 0.07 0.02   0.00
6 0.78 0.87 0.98 0.68 0.76 0.85   0.66
7 0.80 0.46 0.78 0.37 0.62 0.36   0.29
8 0.12 0.64 0.14 0.08 0.02 0.09   0.01
9 0.94 0.52 0.41 0.49 0.39 0.22   0.20

[10 rows x 7 columns]
```

Used input :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=list("abc"))
```

Comment: Great one, there is also a powerset recipe in `itertools` for those who don't want an extra library (which can easily be adjusted to avoid the initial empty set).

Comment: Btw, you should explain the role of `[4:]` and how to generalize. And if you don't assign you could probably use `[1:]`.

Comment: Thanks @mozway, I improved my answer by incorporating your suggestions ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `itertools.combination()` to obtain all combinations of columns for a specified length, and looping over the number of columns to include.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools


df = pd.DataFrame({col: np.random.rand(10) for col in 'abcdef'})


def all_combined_product_cols(df):
    cols = list(df.columns)
    product_cols = []
    for length in range(1, len(cols) + 1):
        for combination in itertools.combinations(cols, r=length):
            combined_col = None
            for col in combination:
                if combined_col is None:
                    combined_col = df[col].copy()
                else:
                    combined_col *= df[col]
            combined_col.name = '_'.join(combination)
            product_cols.append(combined_col)
    return pd.concat(product_cols, axis=1)


print(all_combined_product_cols(df))
```